# Efficiency of Geiger-Muller tube

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation, experimental-technology

What are the factors that affect the efficiency of the Geiger-Muller tube?
*the efficiency of the tube is defined as # of pulses counted per second/total flux entering the detector.

Comment: How does the tube actually work? What are the implications to function for a non-inert of high pressure gas?

Comment: Are you looking for a quantum efficiency? That's mostly a function of particle energy and type. The real problem with e.g. alpha particles is the thickness of the window/tube wall. If the emitter is inside the tube, it has very high QE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- fraction of particles making it into your tube (depends on particles type, energy, angle, location of source and counter, ...)
- fraction of particles interacting within your tube (depends on type, energy, angle).

For typical lab experiments these two will be the smallest efficiencies. But there is also

- fraction of interactions that make it to your central anode... that's probably very close to 1 but you didn't specify your application, so here you go
- Geiger tunes are slow, can take 100 or more microseconds for a pulse, so at rates approaching kilohertz and above you start to miss counts to pile up
- depending on your readout, dead time, i.e. how long after a pulse till you can record another one. Related to pile up but a distinct cause that can depend on your electronics
- in an actual setting, never neglect silly mistakes, e.g. your tube and readout needs to be powered up, the tube in proper working condition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A Geiger tube applies electric field to a gas,
in order to make a dielectric breakdown due to
avalanche carrier generation.   So, the efficiency
depends on the gas actually absorbing the radiation
and ionizing, which means the gas should be
deep enough to be almost opaque to that kind of
radiation, and should (at the energy of interest) eject an electron from a gas molecule.

For this reason, dense gasses like argon are better
than light ones, like helium.

The region of electric field that is high enough to cause electron multiplication by avalanche should be deep enough to make current gain, but that doesn't change the
pulse rate, only the pulse  height.   The radiation path through that sensitive region should be long enough for
the gas to be nearly opaque, but the gas pressure is usually low (to ensure the avalanche doesn't quench too soon).

Additionally, the re-establishment of the field (after the pulse short-circuits the electrodes) should be rapid,
to minimize 'dead time' during the recharging.   For the purpose of recombining the ions  and ending the pulse, a quench gas (often butane) is part of a good Geiger
tube mix.   The efficiency drops off when dead time
is a large fraction of mean pulse separation.